# How to create childnode in ASPxTreeList (devexpress)

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I m beginner of DevExpress tool.
In the Below code, I have bound the parentnode of treeviewlist from sql database.

```
   <dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeList1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                              <Columns>
                                  <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="lastname" VisibleIndex="0">
                                  </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
                                  <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="firstname" VisibleIndex="1">
                                  </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
                                  <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="birthday" VisibleIndex="2">
                                  </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
                              </Columns>
                              <Settings ShowColumnHeaders="False" />
                              <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedNode="True" AutoExpandAllNodes="True" />
                              <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="False" AllowInsert="False" />

                          </dx:ASPxTreeList>                              
                          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [lastname], [firstname], [birthday] FROM [PatientDetails]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now i want to bound the childnode of each parentnode from another table of the sql database.

Please let me know how it is possible with some example.

Thanks,
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ASPxTreeList , but I have used ASPxTreeView whci is pretty good. So for my treeviews I know the following

Using more than one different tables as datasource for your tree is not possible as far as I know. There are two ways to implement what you ask.

1) Create a view and use it as datasource for you tree , by setting the ParentID property of your tree.(if you search the DevExpress knowledge base you will find some solutions [Example](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Tree_List/binding.xml))

2) Add nodes using code,server side (loop throw records etc).